# array objectEnumerator in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have query regarding `objectEnumrator` in Swift. I am converting my code from Objective-C to Swift. In Objective-C, I am able to get enumerator by following ways
 // Create enumerators

```
  NSEnumerator *jsonEnumerator = [mySortedArray objectEnumerator];
  NSDictionary *objectDictionary = [jsonEnumerator nextObject];
```

`mySortedArray` is array of dictionary.

Could you please let me know how can I do this in swift? I am trying to get `mySortedArray.enumerator()` but gives me an enumerator sequence.

Any idea or suggestion would be great.

Comment: I'm not very sure what you mean. Perhaps `mySortedArray.enumerate()`? Or `var array = mySortedArray.generate()` -> `let object = array.next()`?

Comment: It depends on what you are going to accomplish...

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSMutableSet for objectEnumerator.

For example:

```swift
var mySortedArray = NSMutableSet()
let jsonEnumerator: NSEnumerator = mySortedArray.objectEnumerator()
```